# Split a string by any number of spaces

Tags: r, string, strsplit

I have the following string:

```
[1] "10012      ----      ----      ----      ----       CAB    UNCH                    CAB"
```

I want to split this string by the gaps, but the gaps have a variable number of spaces. Is there a way to use `strsplit()` function to split this string and return a vector of 8 elements that has removed all of the gaps?

One line of code is preferred.

Comment: `read.table(text = yourstring)`?

Comment: @Henrik post as answer, please? I have used it million times.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for the heads-up. I'm not quite sure though; OP wants to "return a _vector of 8 elements_", whereas `read.table` would result in a `data.frame` with 8 columns. So it doesn't seem like the right tool here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just use `strsplit` with `\\s+` to split on:

```
x <- "10012      ----      ----      ----      ----       CAB    UNCH       CAB"
x
# [1] "10012      ----      ----      ----      ----       CAB    UNCH       CAB"
strsplit(x, "\\s+")[[1]]
# [1] "10012" "----"  "----"  "----"  "----"  "CAB"   "UNCH"  "CAB"  
length(.Last.value)
# [1] 8
```

---

Or, in this case, `scan` also works:

```
scan(text = x, what = "")
# Read 8 items
# [1] "10012" "----"  "----"  "----"  "----"  "CAB"   "UNCH"  "CAB"
```

Answer (score 19):

strsplit function itself works, by simply using `strsplit(ss, " +")`:

```
ss = "10012      ----      ----      ----      ----       CAB    UNCH                    CAB"

strsplit(ss, " +")
[[1]]
[1] "10012" "----"  "----"  "----"  "----"  "CAB"   "UNCH"  "CAB"
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of whitespaces in the input vector and the number of elements in the output vector, `stringr::str_split_fixed()` is another option.

I reproduced your example below.

```
test <- "10012      ----      ----      ----      ----       CAB    UNCH                    CAB"

stringr::str_split_fixed(test, " {2,}", 8) # at least two white spaces, eight elements
```

This will be the output (the output is a matrix). If you want to turn this into a character vector, just pipe `as.character()`.

```
     [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  [,7]  
[1,] "10012" "----" "----" "----" "----" "CAB" "UNCH"
     [,8] 
[1,] "CAB"
```